# Azure Tables Storage Query returns 501 (Not Implemented)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-table-storage

I have some Data stored in Azure Data Tables and i'm using the following code to query the table:

```
var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(_configuration["StorageConnectionString"]);
var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(TableName);
Pageable<EndpointEntity> queryResultsFilter = tableClient.Query<EndpointEntity>(filter: $"RowKey eq Test");
var entities = queryResultsFilter.ToList();
```

When ran this returns 501 Not Implemented.

```
RequestFailedException: The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.
Status: 501 (Not Implemented)
ErrorCode: NotImplemented
```

I tried removing the .ToList() and using foreach to iterate through instead

```
foreach(var x in queryResultsFilter)
{

}
```

But this returns the same error.

It seems like trying to do anything on the `Pageable<EndpointEntity>` is causing the 501 error.  My EndPointEntity Looks like this:

```
 public class EndpointEntity : ITableEntity
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public DateTime PerformanceDate { get; set; }
        public double TotalProcessingTimeMilliseconds { get; set; }
        public string JourneyID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
        public ETag ETag { get; set; }
        DateTimeOffset? ITableEntity.Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Which seems to be valid so I'm not sure why my query is returning an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because of your filter expression - try enclosing the search value in your filter in single quotes:

```
Pageable<EndpointEntity> queryResultsFilter 
    = tableClient.Query<EndpointEntity>(filter: $"RowKey eq 'Test'");
```